# Javadoc of package-private interface's methods is not inherited since Java 9

Tags: java, javadoc, java-9

I have a public class that implements a package-private interface. I noticed that the javadoc of the interface's methods is no longer inherited since OpenJDK 9. I tested this with OpenJDK 9, 11, and 16.

It does not matter if the implementation method in the class has no javadoc at all or javadoc with the `{@inheritDoc}` tag. In both cases no javadoc from the interface is inherited.

This is an example:

```
public class PublicClass implements PackagePrivateInterface {
  @Override public void sampleMethod() {}
}

interface PackagePrivateInterface {
    /** This javadoc is not inherited */ void sampleMethod();
}
```

Inheritance still works for public interfaces and for package-private classes/abstract classes. Is there a reason that this kind of inheritance of javadoc from package-private interfaces is no longer supported?

Comment: how were you inheriting the Javadoc until now? a sample code if you could share, would be good to reproduce this.

Comment: Good point, I added some sample code.

Comment: Do you use `-private`? Otherwise I think that JavaDoc will just generally be ignored (and I'd consider earlier versions using it for inheritance to be bug). Put differently: I wouldn't expect to inherit JavaDoc that's not itself considered for output in a given run.

Comment: No I don't use -private. For me it would be convenient if the javadoc would be inherited because this way I can prevent duplicate JavaDoc without making the internal interface public. When following your reasoning there would still be a bug: javadoc of package private classes is inherited.